# CA certificate for TLS connection node02.myqtthub.com/8883

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, mqtt, esp32

I'm playing with mqtthub and ESP32 CHIP. I would like to connect in most secure way so i thought maybe try with TLS connection at the beginning and later i could also encrypt data which is sent to broker(mqtthub).
I successfully managed to connect with mosquitto on linux using **/etc/ssl/certs path** to CA certificates.

I would like now to copy the certificate I need into flash memory that my app written in C can use it while it connects to broker on port 8883. How can i guess which one public CA  certificate is the right one i need to copy from /etc/ssl/certs ?

PS: i found this on mqtthub forum:
https://decoder.link/sslchecker/node02.myqtthub.com/8883
might it be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i found the solution. Instead of pointing to entire directiory

```
mosquitto_sub -h node02.myqtthub.com -p 8883 --capath /etc/mosquitto/certs -i linux_machine -u nariox -P myPassword -t test/connection -q 2
```

i run the command with cafile instead of capath

```
mosquitto_sub -h node02.myqtthub.com -p 8883 --cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt -i linux_machine -u nariox -P myPassword -t test/connection -q 2
```

what solved my problem. If anyone could explain it to my why i will be grateful

Comment: Read the man page for `mosquitto_sub` it explains the difference between`--capath` and `--cafile`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the certificate chain returned from your server I see the root certificate has a common name `DST Root CA X3`:

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect node02.myqtthub.com:8883
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1                                                       
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = node02.myqtthub.com                                      
verify return:1
```

The directory `/etc/ssl/certs` in my host happens to contain a cert named `DST_Root_CA_X3.pem`. This would be a good candidate to try.

Comment: HI @Tarmo, thanks for YOur suggestions. Unfortunately DS_ROOT_CA_X3.pem is not only the one certificate i need ( i dont know why). I copied the entire certs folder from /etc/ssl/cert into new lociation and delete all files apart from DS_Root_CA_X3.pem. Connection cant be established. In the second try i deleted only DS_Root_CA_X3.pem and  the connection cant be established as well. So i guess i need something more :( if i start mosquitto and give the new location of unchanged certs folder it connects.

Comment: The problem lies with the mosquitto client - run it with verbose output to debug it.
Running `openssl` with just the single certificate successfully validates the entire x509 chain from your server, so it has to be the correct one:

$ openssl s_client -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/DST_Root_CA_X3.pem -showcerts -connect node02.myqtthub.com:8883

Comment: Hi @Tarmo. I solved the issue using cafile instead of capath.